# Deleting record via has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-many

My model schema:

User

```
has_many :activities
has_many :companies through: :activities
```

Company

```
has_many :activities
has_many :users, through: :activities
```

Activity

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

Problem when I try to run `current_user.activities.delete_all(["company_id=?", params[:id]])` or `clear` or `destroy` I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from /home/rom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:156:in `delete_all'
    from /home/rom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `delete_all'
```

Comment: `delete_all` doesn't expect arguments. You're trying to delete_all records for a particular filter.
Read the doc here - http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/3.2.6/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation:delete_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
Activity.delete_all(["company_id=? AND user_id=?", params[:id], current_user.id])
```